# sapui5 ReBind data in table from odata

Tags: sapui5

i got a rendered table with odata

This is my controller:

```
var oTable = this.getTable();
        var oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "OBJ_KEY");

        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"OBJ_KEY"}),
            template :oControl,
            sortProperty :"OBJ_KEY",
            filterProperty :"OBJ_KEY",
            width :"10%"
        }));

      oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "OBJ_TXT");

      oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
          label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"OBJ_TXT"}),
          template :oControl,
          sortProperty :"OBJ_TXT",
          filterProperty :"OBJ_TXT",
          width :"40%"
          }));
      oTable.setModel(this.oModel);
      var oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("OBJ_KEY");
      oTable.bindRows("/MATGR1", oSorter);
```

This is my View:

```
<Table id="sap_m_Page_0-content-build_simple_Table-1534593457799" width="50%" noDataText="No data" mode="None" showSeparators="All" growing="true" growingThreshold="20" growingScrollToLoad="true" items="{plants>/MATGR1}">
                            <infoToolbar>
                                <Toolbar width="100%" height="auto" design="Auto" visible="false" enabled="true">
                                    <content>
                                        <Label text="Label" design="Standard" width="100%" required="false" textAlign="Begin" textDirection="Inherit" visible="true"/>
                                    </content>
                                </Toolbar>
                            </infoToolbar>
                            <headerToolbar>
                                <OverflowToolbar width="auto" height="auto" design="Transparent" visible="true" enabled="true">
                                    <content>
                                        <Title text="Розничный торговый оборот" titleStyle="Auto" width="auto" textAlign="Begin" visible="true" wrapping="false"/>
                                        <ToolbarSpacer width=""/>
                                        <OverflowToolbarButton text="Sort" type="Transparent" icon="sap-icon://sort" iconFirst="true" width="auto" enabled="true" visible="true" iconDensityAware="false" press="_onOverflowToolbarButtonPress"/>
                                        <OverflowToolbarButton text="Filter" type="Transparent" icon="sap-icon://filter" iconFirst="true" width="auto" enabled="true" visible="true" iconDensityAware="false" press="_onOverflowToolbarButtonPress1"/>
                                        <OverflowToolbarButton text="Group" type="Transparent" icon="sap-icon://group-2" iconFirst="true" width="auto" enabled="true" visible="true" iconDensityAware="false" press="_onOverflowToolbarButtonPress2"/>
                                        <OverflowToolbarButton text="Settings" type="Transparent" icon="sap-icon://action-settings" iconFirst="true" width="auto" enabled="true" visible="true" iconDensityAware="false" press="_onOverflowToolbarButtonPress3"/>
                                    </content>
                                </OverflowToolbar>
                            </headerToolbar>
                            <columns>
                                <Column width="auto" hAlign="Left" vAlign="Top" minScreenWidth="Phone" demandPopin="false" popinDisplay="Inline" mergeDuplicates="false">
                                    <header>
                                        <Text text="Наименование" width="auto" maxLines="1" wrapping="false" textAlign="Begin" textDirection="Inherit" visible="true"/>
                                    </header>
                                    <footer/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column width="auto" hAlign="Left" vAlign="Top" minScreenWidth="Phone" demandPopin="false" popinDisplay="Inline" mergeDuplicates="false">
                                    <header>
                                        <Text text="Сумма" width="auto" maxLines="1" wrapping="false" textAlign="Begin" textDirection="Inherit" visible="true"/>
                                    </header>
                                    <footer/>
                                </Column>
                            </columns>
                            <items>
                                <ColumnListItem type="Active" press="_onRowPress">
                                    <cells>
                                         <ObjectIdentifier title="{plants>OBJ_KEY}" text="{plants>OBJ_TXT}" titleActive="false" visible="true"/> 
                                    </cells>
                                </ColumnListItem>
                            </items>
                        </Table>
```

So what I want to do next: when I click on a row in my table, the table should refresh its data on its own. It is like a hierarchy, because at the first time in table we have categories like: "food, accessories etc" and when i click on food (for ex.) the table should refresh the data to "milk products, sweets, beverages etc". But I've got a problem with the refreshing, because SAP doesn't allow refreshing data when its already bound.

My onpress event:

```
var oTable = this.byId("sap_m_Page_0-content-build_simple_Table-1534593457799");

        var oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "OBJ_KEY");
        oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "OBJ_TXT");

        oTable.setModel(this.oModel);
        var oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("OBJ_KEY");
        oTable.bindRows("/MATGR2", oSorter);
```

Comment: @Erch, my bad, thnks

Answer (score 1):

First of all we should delete all items from our table. Therefore we select our own table this way:

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("TABLE_ID");
```

Then we clear our table from data:

```
oTable.unbindItems();
```

And bind new items:

```
oTable.bindItems("OUR_MODEL>/OUR_DATA_VIEW",
    new sap.m.ColumnListItem( {
        type: "Active",
        cells: [
                new sap.m.Text({ label: "{OUR_MODEL>VIEW_ITEM}", text: "{OUR_MODEL>VIEW_ITEM}" })
              ]
    })
);
```

That all.